# Move config files out of project root (webpack)

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, babeljs

My Project root is full of config files for various packages and deployments (`.eslintrc`,`.prettierrc`,`.editorconfig`,`.env`,`.babelrc` etc...).

Is there a better way to manage them than putting them all into my project root?

Comment: I do not think so - I think some of these are hardcoded (at least `.editorconfig` and `.env`) The default location of others can be changed through the Webpack config - e.g. for PostCSS it will be `{ css:
  {
    sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    loaderOptions:
    {
      postcss:
      {
        config:
        {
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'config', '.postcssrc.js'),
        }
      }
    }    
  }`